# What means "hat sich gut geschlagen"?

Tags: meaning

I have a friend who was afraid of ice skating and apparently she did pretty well in the end. So her partner said:

> "Sie hat sich sehr gut geschlagen"

I was wondering if she had started to punch herself in the face, but apparently this means that she forced herself to do it.

Is this correct? Has `schlagen` a different meaning when used in a reflexive way?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schlagen#Bedeutung8c

Comment: It's in a very, very figurative sense! It implies a _difficult_ or _challenging_ situation (voluntary or forced) and the behaviour and handling of such. Imagine a boxing match. You don't have to be neccessarily successful to _sich gut geschlagen haben_. You just made a convincing  performance under given circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it this way: if you defeat someone (e.g. in sports or competitions), we call it *jemanden schlagen*. In case of *sich selbst schlagen*, you kinda defeated yourself — in a positive way. That is, you overcame your weaknesses or you achieved something you didn't think you could.
Note, this is just an approach how to understand it; I'm not saying this is the origin of its meaning.

Though, depending on context, *sich schlagen* can also mean to hit oneself.

> Ich habe am Ball vorbeigeschlagen und mich versehentlich selbst mit dem Schläger geschlagen.

And a further meaning is *to fight each other*.

> Hört auf, euch zu schlagen.

So, it's all about context, but the collocation "sich (sehr) gut schlagen" usually refers to doing well.

Comment: This is a great way of putting it. I also understand what you mean, with "defeating yourself". It is a good way of remembering its meaning in the context. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: This explanation is quite far from how I understand the expression.

Comment: Could it be used synonym with "Sie hat sich sehr gut durchgeführt"

Comment: Native german speaker here. It has nothing to do with beating each other. It just means to do something very well.

Answer (score 4):

If somebody say "Er hat sich gut geschlagen" it means that he was doing well or he made something quite good. In this case it has nothing to do with punching or fighting.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works. Also, consider registering if you want to contribute more.

Answer (score 3):

### schlagen

Der Begriff »sich schlagen« kommt aus einer Zeit, wo kriegerische Schlachten noch auf dem Boden von Kämpfern mit Äxten, Schwertern und anderen Nahkampfwaffen gefochten wurden. Man hat also tatsächlich mit allerlei Gerätschaften, und zur Not auch mit bloßen Fäusten, auf den Gegner eingeschlagen.

### sich

Das Relativpronomen »sich« kann auf drei Arten benutzt werden:

1. Als Reflexivpronomen der dritten Person Singular:

   > Werner kauft **sich** ein Auto.

   Das bedeutet: Werner kauft ein Auto, das für ihn selbst bestimmt ist.
2. Als Reflexivpronomen der dritten Person Plural:

   > Herr und Frau Müller kaufen sich ein Haus.

   Das bedeutet: Herr und Frau Müller kaufen gemeinsam ein Haus, das für beide (und somit für jeden einzelnen von ihnen) bestimmt ist.
3. Die anderen Personen aus derselben Gruppe:

   > Jürgen, Manfred und Walter bekämpfen sich.

   Das bedeutet nicht, dass jeder der drei gegen sich selbst kämpft, und es bedeutet auch nicht, dass die drei als vereinte Gruppe gegen eine Drei-Personen-Gruppe kämpfen, die sie zufällig selbst sind.

   Dieser Satz bedeutet, dass Jürgen, Manfred und Walter eine Gruppe bilden, innerhalb der einzelne Mitglieder gegen andere Mitglieder kämpfen. Jürgen kämpft gegen einen der beiden anderen oder gegen beide, und dasselbe gilt auch für Manfred und Walter. Jeder bekämpft mindestens eine Person aus der Gruppe zu der man selbst gehört, aber keiner bekämpft sich selbst.

Der Ausdruck

> sich schlagen

bedeutet genau das, was im letzen Punkt beschrieben wurde: Man befindet sich in einer Gruppe kämpfender Menschen und kämpft gegen einen oder mehrere dieser Menschen. Im Extremfall kämpft jeder gegen alle anderen in der Gruppe. Auch möglich ist, dass die Gruppe in mehrere Parteien aufgeteilt ist, wobei die Mitglieder einer Partei Mitglieder anderer Parteien bekämpfen. Welche Einzelperson genau gegen welche andere Einzelperson kämpft, kann aus »sie bekämpfen sich« ohne weitere Informationen nicht geschlossen werden, aber klar ist, dass niemand gegen sich selbst kämpft.

### gut

Bei diesen Kämpfen kann man erfolgreich sein, also den Gegner besiegen, oder auch dem Gegner unterliegen. In dem einen Fall schlägt man sich gut, im anderen schlägt man sich schlecht.

Sportliche Wettkämpfe haben sich aus militärischen Kämpfen, bzw. aus den Vorbereitungen darauf entwickelt, und so ist es auch kein Wunder, dass viele Begriffe der Kriegsführung auch im Sport Verwendung finden. »Sich schlagen« ist einer dieser Begriffe.

Wenn also jemand in einem sportlichen Wettkampf besser als der Gegner abschneidet, dann hat man sich gut geschlagen. Aber das Vorhandensein eines direkten Gegners ist gar nicht mehr erforderlich. Sich gut zu schlagen kann auch bedeuten, dass man eine gute Leistung erbracht hat.

Comment: Sehr gute erklärung. Ergänzung: der kampf muss sich nicht ausschließlich auf menschen beziehen. Es geht auch zb "Bei der Deutschprüfung hat er sich gut geschlagen."

Comment: @BerndGit: Ja, das ist ziemlich genau das, was ich in den letzten beiden Sätzen auszudrücken versucht habe